# Keep this countdown from restart on browser refresh and remove mouse click during countdown

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown that needs to not reset on page refreshes. Could anyone show me what would suit best for my current code? I also would like some input if it's possible to disable any kind of mouseclick or if another apporach is the way to go to make the user unable to go somewhere else on the page during countdown. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Mine is not a duplicate since it includes remove of mouse click during countdown and my goal os a lot different from that post.

```js
var time = 30;
function countdown()
{
  if(time==0)
  {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
    tmptime = time;
    dayTime = 24*60*60;
    hourTime = 60*60;
    minutesTime = 60;

    days = Math.floor(tmptime/dayTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - days*dayTime;

    hours = Math.floor(tmptime/hourTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - hours*hourTime;

    minutes = Math.floor(tmptime/minutesTime);
    tmptime = tmptime - minutes*minutesTime;

    seconds = tmptime;
    tidtext="";
    if(days>0)
      tidtext = days+ hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else if(hours>0)
      tidtext = hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    else
      tidtext =  minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";

      document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = tidtext;
    document.getElementById('timer').classList.add('timer');
    time--;
    setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<td data-th="Workout"><input type="submit" onclick="countdown();" value="Bench Press"></td>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using local storage or cookies to store data across refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("time", time);
```

will set the value of `time` into localStorage. You could do this in every iteration of the loop. Then, on page load you could do

```
time = localStorage.getItem("time");
```

to retrieve the value of `time` from localStorage.